# Using an array in SELECT IN query?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to know if it is possible to create a query where the WHERE clause has one condition but the value is an array.

This is the code & image related table in the database:

[image]

```
//array in user.id_lokasi => (PL001,PL002,PL003)    
SELECT * FROM `lokasi` 
         WHERE `id_lokasi` IN (SELECT id_lokasi FROM user WHERE id_user='admin')
```

Comment: Yes, Your query is correct!

Comment: If i type manually SELECT * FROM `lokasi` 
     WHERE `id_lokasi` IN ('PL001', 'PL002', 'PL003'); its correct, but when i select from table user there is no data show

Comment: You need to normalize your database, you should not have a list of keys in a single database field.

Answer (score 2):

Your query above should work already. Regarding your question if you have a set of id_lokasi you want to use in the WHERE you can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM `lokasi` 
     WHERE `id_lokasi` IN ('PL001', 'PL002', 'PL003');
```

As to your original query, you could rewrite it like this to avoid the subquery:

```
SELECT l.* FROM `lokasi` l
LEFT JOIN user u ON
    u.id_lokasi = l.id_locasi AND u.id_user = 'admin'
```

Comment: when I change the parameters in u.id_user='user', all data appears... I just want to bring up the data based on array id_lokasi in user table.